# Enable Recent Comments widget to display comments on attachment posts

Tags: comments

Is it possible to hook into the default Recent Comments widget to enable it to display comments for attachment posts? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the `widget_comments_args` filter to modify the default args of the recent comments widget:

```
function wpse80087_widget_comments_args( $args )
{
    $args = array( 'number' => 5, 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'status' => 'approve', 'post_status' => 'inherit' );
    return $args;
}
add_filter( 'widget_comments_args', 'wpse80087_widget_comments_args', 10, 1 );
```

Comment: It displays the widget title only, no comments.

Comment: Yes, sorry, post_status should have been inherit, I edited my answer

Comment: Check that: now it displays only the comments on attachment posts.

Comment: Apologies for not being clear: Is it possible for the widget to display all comments, including attachments?                                                   'post_type' => array('attachment', 'page', 'post'),

Comment: Works perfect! To merge all comments you limit it to 'status' => 'approve' Thanks!