# Display attachment, post and page in recent comments widget

Tags: widgets, comments

The following code (old post is [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/80087/enable-recent-comments-widget-to-display-comments-on-attachment-posts) and author is [diggy](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/25765/diggy)) is useful, but i'd like display post and page on recent comments widget, not only attachments.

```
function wpse80087_widget_comments_args( $args )
{
    $args = array( 'number' => 5, 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'status' => 'approve', 'post_status' => 'inherit' );
    return $args;
}
add_filter( 'widget_comments_args', 'wpse80087_widget_comments_args', 10, 1 );
```

Is it possible?

---

SOLUTION:

Thanks to [Pieter Goosen](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/31545/pieter-goosen) and [Birgire](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/26350/birgire).

**First step:**

[Plugin](https://github.com/birgire/wp-comments-from-mulitple-post-types)

**Second step:**

function.php

```
function wpse80087_widget_comments_args( $args ) {
    $args = array( 
       'number' => 9, 
       'post_type' => array('attachment', 'post', 'page'),
    );
    return $args;
}
add_filter( 'widget_comments_args', 'wpse80087_widget_comments_args', 10, 1 );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does seem that you are already using a custom function that you found from this site. You should credit the original author of that code.

The `widget_comments_args` filter was introduced in Wordpress3.4. This filter is poorly documented. This filter uses [`get_comments()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_comments), so you can also use the same parameters. Here is the filter in [*wp-includes/default-widgets.php#L847*](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.9.1/src/wp-includes/default-widgets.php#L847)

```
847                 /**
848                  * Filter the arguments for the Recent Comments widget.
849                  *
850                  * @since 3.4.0
851                  *
852                  * @see get_comments()
853                  *
854                  * @param array $comment_args An array of arguments used to retrieve the recent comments.
855                  */
856                 $comments = get_comments( apply_filters( 'widget_comments_args', array(
857                         'number'      => $number,
858                         'status'      => 'approve',
859                         'post_status' => 'publish'
860                 ) ) );
```

There is a problem though in `get_comments()` as it only accepts one post type, not an array or a string which is actually quite funny. There is away around this.

One of the members of the site [@birgire](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/26350/birgire) has written a plugin called [wp-comments-from-mulitple-post-types](https://github.com/birgire/wp-comments-from-mulitple-post-types/blob/master/README.md) to add the ability to `get_comments` and `WP_Comment_Query()` to accept multiple post types. You can download his plugin [here](https://github.com/birgire/wp-comments-from-mulitple-post-types/archive/master.zip)

After installation, you can now use your code like this

```
function wpse80087_widget_comments_args( $args ) {
    $args = array( 
       'number' => 5, 
       'post_type' => array('attachment', 'post',' page'),
     );
    return $args;
}
add_filter( 'widget_comments_args', 'wpse80087_widget_comments_args', 10, 1 );
```

**EDIT**

It seems that from feedback from the OP that either `status` or `post_status` is not working and only returns one post type. When these parameters are removed, everything works as expected. See the updated code above

Comment: Maybe this should be fixed in core?

Answer (score 0):

Use the widget_posts_args to modify the args in the get_comments functions for that default widget.

Something like this:

```
function wpsites_widget_comments_args( $args ) {
$args = array( 
'post_type'   => array( 'attachment', 'post', 'page'),
'number'      => $number,
'status'      => 'approve',
'post_status' => 'publish'  );

return $args;
}
add_filter( 'widget_comments_args', 'wpsites_widget_comments_args', 10, 1 );
```

You can use any of the [`get_comments`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_comments) Parameters otherwise you can copy over the [`code for the recent comments widget`](https://github.com/braddalton/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/default-widgets.php#L688) from WordPress > wp-includes > default-widgets.php file and replace the get_comments function with WP_Query to create a custom recent comments widget in your child theme or plugin

Comment: Thank you Brad. Your code doesn't work. I'll try with a custom widget if there aren't solutions.

Comment: O.K Probably because the get_comments function doesn't accept the parameters you need to modify. You can use those args in the new WP_Query so still useful.

Comment: Looks like my code is fine but needs the plugin installed first as its a bug in WordPress. https://github.com/birgire/wp-comments-from-mulitple-post-types/blob/master/README.md